# Error al pasar o empaquetar archivo .py a .exe (python a .exe)

Tags: python

Trato de empaquetar .py en .exe con pyinstaller de la siguiente manera `pyinstaller --onefile script.py` pero obtengo un error relacionado con un archivo .dll, he intentado cargar el dll que esta en la misma carpeta que script.py de la siguiente manera `pyinstaller.exe -F --add-data "./libsecp256k1.dll;." script.py` pero no lo toma, sigue arrojando el mismo error, alguna sugerencia o ayuda para poder resolver el error seria de gran ayuda para mi; Gracias de antemano.

**El codigo que intento empaquetar de .py a .exe es el siguiente.**

```
from coincurve import PublicKey

print("Probando python")
```

**Uso la libreria de python llamada coincurve `pip install coincurve`**

**Este es el archivo `.spec` que me genera pyinstaller.**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['script.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\CCP\\Desktop\\1'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('./libsecp256k1.dll', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='script',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

**Este es el error que me genera al ejecutar el `.exe` que se creo con pyintaller.**

```
C:\Users\CCP\Desktop\1\dist>121
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "121.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\ccp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\Py
Installer\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\coincurve\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\ccp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\Py
Installer\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\coincurve\context.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\ccp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\Py
Installer\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\coincurve\flags.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\ccp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\Py
Installer\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\coincurve\_libsecp256k1.py", line 239, in <module>
  File "site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 150, in dlopen
  File "site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 832, in _make_ffi_library
  File "site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 827, in _load_backend_lib
OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Users\CCP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI46962\coincurv
e\libsecp256k1.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did n
ot manage to locate a library called 'C:\\Users\\CCP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI
46962\\coincurve\\libsecp256k1.dll'
[4380] Failed to execute script 121

C:\Users\CCP\Desktop\1\dist>
```

Comment: no te puedo decir que este sea el caso, pero pyinstaller hace mucho que da problemas con los antivirus, desactivalo y fijate si sigue dando errores.

Comment: tincopasan, gracias por responder, intente lo que dijiste, desactive el antivirus pero parece que ese no es el problema por que ejecute de nuevo el .exe que genero pyinstaller y me arroja el mismo error que ya mencione.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando compilas una aplicación con *pyinstaller* con el argumento `--onefile` y lo ejecutas, todos los recursos que contiene el ejecutable se descomprimen en un directorio temporal. Este directorio temporal es diferente cada vez que ejecutas la aplicación, pero su dirección es almacenada en la variable `sys._MEIPASS`.

**El problema es que el directorio de trabajo de tu aplicación** (que puede obtenerse con `os.getcwd()`) **es aquel en el que se encuentra el ejecutable, pero los recursos se extraen en `sys._MEIPASS`.**

La variable `sys._MEIPASS` solamente existe cuando has compilado con el argumento `--onefile`, de modo que la solución mas sencilla es añadir lo siguiente al inicio del script:

```py
import sys, os

if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
```

De esta forma el directorio de trabajo será aquel en el que se han extraidos los recursos de tu ejecutable.

Un saludo!

Comment: tecnobillo, agradezco a tu ayuda y comentario, pero aplicando lo que dijiste al script, sigo teniendo exactamente el mismo error :( tengo ya unos días sin encontrar solución.

Comment: *Pyinstaller* da muchos dolores de cabeza con `--onefile` (a pesar de todas sus virtudes). Quizás cambiando `"./libsecp256k1.dll;."` por `"libsecp256k1.dll;."` (sin el **./** inicial) en el comando de compilación funcione. [Este link puede serte útil](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Win-Load-External-DLL). Puede que tengas que *importar ctypes* antes de lo que dije en la respuesta. Un saludo y suerte!

Comment: tecnobillo, amigo, sigo sin encontrar solución al problema, sabes o conoces otra forma o librería que me permita empaquetar .py en .exe ?

Comment: Está *cx_freeze*, pero lo mas sencillo es *pyinstaller*. Si lo compilas sin `--onefile` funciona bien? En ese caso puedes omitirlo y crear un instalador con [InstallForge](https://installforge.net/). Otra opción un poco mas compleja es [InnoSetup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).